# Creating a Date Column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

[image: Report.csv]Here's the code:

```
data = read.csv('Report.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white=TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
data = data.frame(Date = "2009-04-18", data)
data$Date = as.Date(data$Date, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

It keeps giving me the charToDate(x) error

> (character string is not in a standard unambiguous format).

I have 0 idea what is wrong. My ultimate goal is to create a date column in this data frame.

Comment: How about using zoo package to read csv files? `data <- read.zoo("Report.csv",
                sep = ',', 
                tz = '',   
                header = TRUE,
                format = '%Y/%m/%d')`

Comment: The file is VERY messy. There is no prior date column, I'm extracting it from other columns. That's why I'm trying to create a data column after reading it.

Comment: try changing to: `data$Date = as.Date(data$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: IMPORTANT EDIT: when I run the code manually, block by block, it works as intended. But I only receive this error message when I knit HTML. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @sammuh: can you create a minimum [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Your date variable is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`, not `YYYY/MM/DD`. You are trying to tell R that your separator for your date variable is `/` instead of `-` (which is what it actually is). That said, this should do the trick:

`data$Date = as.Date(data$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: We could be of more use if you produced a reproducible example, we have no idea what `Report.csv` looks like.

Comment: I attached a picture of what the csv looks like when I import it. I'm simply adding a date column to this data frame